# Can I force Crashlytics to call a script "run" in the current thread?

Tags: xcode, crashlytics

I have my own script through which I create a temporary folder for `derivedDataPath`. as soon as the script works and creates an IPA file, the `derivedDataPath` folder is deleted. But at the last stage of the build, I added a call:

```
Script:
${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run
Input Files:
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
${SRCROOT}/${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}
```

He informs me that everything is fine and the upload will be completed in the background:

```
Running upload-symbols in Build Phase mode
Validating build environment for Crashlytics...
Validation succeeded. Symbol uploading will proceed in the background.
```

But in my IPA file creation script, the `derivedDataPath` folder will be deleted. Perhaps for this reason, the data is not being uploaded. How can I check the completion of the upload?

Now I have a console hanging in Firebase that there are no dSYM files for the desired version And I don't understand what's wrong with the Update not through the Appstore, but through air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the "run" script, you can call the "upload-symbols" script adding the --build-phase flag:

`${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase`

This will make the script to upload the dSYMs as part of the build process instead of doing it in the background.