# dSYMs missing in Crashlytics, maybe of local Swift Packages

Tags: swift, crashlytics, dsym, symbolicate

We use Crashlytics for crash reports and recently we started to receive warnings that some dSYMs are missing. The main latest changes are the switch to Xcode 14 that brought disabling bitcode, and the introduction of local Swift Packages.

The UUID of these missing dSYMs are not in the generated DSYMs, only in the "symbols" folder of the created IPA, as ".symbol" file.

All targets and CocoaPods dependencies are set with "DWARF with dSYM File". I could not find any settings for Swift Packages (both external and local) but as far as I understood they will use the app target setting.

According to [Is there a way to generate dSYMs for Swift Packages when Xcode archiving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71139977/is-there-a-way-to-generate-dsyms-for-swift-packages-when-xcode-archiving):

> By default swift packages are compiled as static libraries so that its
> binaries will be inserted in your app's binary and all symbolication
> info will be inside "YourApp.dSYM" under __swift_ast section.

I checked in the app dSYM, but could not find in it any "__swift_ast" section.

Could that be the reason of the missing dSYMs, and is there any setting that would prevent the creation of the "__swift_ast" section?

I contacted Bitrise (our CI that make the build and upload dSYMs) and Crashlytics support, with no success.

Comment: If you are using a run script to upload the dSYMs, this typically runs asynchronously. Sometimes in CI environments the thread is closed before the dSYMs get uploaded. Could you try using this script instead to upload the dSYMs as part of the build process? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71505743/4044241

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not an upload problem, even after uploading manually the generated dSYMs in the Crashlytics UI, they are missing. The missing dSYMs are simply not generated and not to be found in the build.